# One half of my object is darker than the other

Tags: modeling

I just cut an object in half and then mirrored it. 
Before i joined the objects, they looked perfectly similar, but after joining, one half is darker than the other.
I tried some stuff and i did delete doubles, and i checked the material
but it all doesn't help

That's the thing, after joining the 2 halves:
[image: thats the thing, after joining the 2 halves]

Answer (score 3):

I have 2 possible solutions. One, try (in edit mode) pressing {control n} which will recalculate the normals. If the normals are incorrect then it will fix that. Otherwise, it's just a question of shading.

Comment: Alt-N for the menu of options in 2.8x

Answer (score 0):

My solution is. Roughness set it to 1.0.
I'm creating character, I really don't know how to do. But when I did it. It goes fine.
Maybe after applying Mirror then that's the time to adjust roughness again if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Mirror modifier.
Object Mode > CRTL+A,
Apply all transformation,
then add Mirror Modifier again.

Hahahahaha can't believe I remember that 4 seconds to some videos I watch.